# I have a Podfile in the project, but No `Podfile' found in the project directory

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

recently I bought new macbook 16(intel, catalina)
I have started new project, I cannot install pods in my xcode project.
I successfully installed cocoapods and pod init.
but I cannot run command pod install.

[image: Pod]

[image: no podfile]

[image]

This is what I get when I type command

```
ruby -rrbconfig -e 'puts RbConfig::CONFIG["rubyhdrdir"]'
```

/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/include/ruby-2.6.0

Please help if you have similar experience or good guess.
Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried uncommenting the `platform : iOS, '9.0'` in your pod file? Also are you doing `pod install` in the same folder where the `Podfile` is?

Comment: @amagain 1. No, I have not tried uncommenting. it doesn't solve my problem. 2. Yes, I do

Comment: have you solve the issue?

Comment: have the same at new mac when first installing cocoapods and deploying existing project

Answer (score 0):

I had the same message about no 'Podfile'. I've solved this by moving my project to different directory with simple path. The previous one was too complicated - with backspaces, foreign language characters, with special characters.I think, the installer didn't like something about that.